# Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client

Tags: apex, callout, tls

Environment : Sandbox

I am using callout to pull the data from api to Salsesforce. It was working untill salesforce disable TLS 1.0. Today I ran the apex callout and got the following error

> System.CalloutException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version
>   is not enabled or not supported by the client

Then I checked Internet about this error and came to know that salesforce disabled TLS 1.0. I also got some information TLS 1.0 Disablement Critical Update Console (CRUC) Setting. But unfortunately am not able to see that **Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections** in CRUC.

Then I checked my callout url using [Qualysis SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and got the result like below
[image]

So, my callout url api is not supported for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

Now what action I need to take to work properly again.

Thanks.

**Update** : My Chrome Browser is up to date with Supporting TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, you will need to update the endpoint server to enable TLS 1.1 or above.

Here are details on how you can enable TLS 1.1 and above : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207#OutboundIntegrations

If this third party sever/endpoint is not in your control then you will have to request sever owner for upgrade.

If that is not possible then you will have to create a middle-ware which can communicate with both TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1 and above.

Then from salesforce you need to send send request to your middle-ware/agent and from agent send it to the actual 3rd party.

PS: This disablement is for only sandbox for now and production org will continue to work till March 4, 2017. Although its not advisable to wait till March 4, 2017.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We are using third party server so we cannot do anything on this. Now have to rise about this issue to my representative to speak with that third party owner. Otherwise have to do some heavy work to solve this.